# Many to many relationship from different column other than id in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm having two models `Project` and `StartYear` I'm having a `project_technical_details` table which holds most of the project information. So I've following table structure in `project_technical_details`:

```
project_id    construction_start    construction_area   floors .....
```

When we were developing we were storing construction_start as year. i.e. it was hard coded for ex `2012`, `2013`, `2019` etc...
Now we want to establish a relationship by which we can manipulate data, so we created a model `StartYear` and we have following table structure:

```
id   year  created_at   updated_at
```

so in this model I defined relationship as:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Project', 'project_technical_details', 'construction_start', 'project_id');
}
```

But in this case I want to relate with `year` column not with the `id`. How can I achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: Is year is unique ? How you will identify the associated record in your model?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu yes values are unique, but column is not defined as unique in mysql

Comment: Then create another migration and set it as unique.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu ok, but how can I define the same in relationship/model?

Comment: In your pivot table, you will take your year column and unique column from other model.

Answer (score 0):

Your pivot table should look like this:

```
|------------------------|
| year | project_id | ...|
|------------------------|
```

Then, in your `StartYear` model:

```php
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Project', 'project_techinical_details', 'project_id', 'year'
    )
        ->whereColumn('project_techinical_details.construction_start', 'start_year.year');
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So I have to modify my `project_technical_details` table or the `start_year` table?

Comment: Wait.. I think i missed something. You need the Project models from `project_technical_details` table, right? If so, your relationship is correct.

Comment: yes, but related to `year` column from `StartYear` not with the `id`

Comment: StartYear has a relation with Project or with project_techinical_details?

Comment: With Project, but relationship information (pivot table) is project_technical_details which has project_id and year

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer. If i am correct, when you call `->projects` from `StartYear` instance, it will return all projects which started in this year.

Comment: Not getting desired results, I'm getting only project_id related to that year. Like suppose  `1901` is start year it is showing me `project_id` which is `1901`. Hope you are getting my point.

Comment: But that is exactly what the `belongsToMany` relationship does. If your start year is 1901, it will return only projects which started in 1901. Why it is not correct?

Comment: `construction_start` column in `project_technical_details` should match `year` in `start_year` table.

Comment: I upated my answer again. If the table names are ok, it should work.